# How to dynamically fetch value from url in XSLT

Tags: url, xslt

I have a url of type C:/Documents and Settings/Saxon/output1/index.html?value=65abc

Now i need to fetch this part from url '65abc' in my xslt. I am getting this value from the previous page when click on a link.

Any idea of how to do it?

Comment: The XSL cannot by itself access URL variables - you would need to pass these in manually. What platform are you running XSL on? In PHP, for example, you'd use `$process->setParameter`. Then, as long as your XSL declared the variable, it would receive it, and you could reference it.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I am doing XML to HTML conversion using XSLT. I want to have 2 html files for which I am using Saxon. In the first file I have link and when I click on link, a value is sent to the url. For doing this I am using - <a href="index.html?value={$cd}"> 
Now when I click on the link I am able to get the value in url and now I need to use the value from the url in my XSLT to display other details.

Comment: That is not a URL, it is a Windows filename.

Comment: but still how to get the value from it. If I am running the files on my system.

Comment: I'm still unclear on what platform you're doing all this on. If it's Saxon, are you using Java or .NET? Or do you mean you're doing the XSL via JavaScript? Whichever one, you need to retrieve the URL vars and then manually pass them in to your XSL (in the case of JavaScript, this is not always possible, depending on browser). XSL cannot normally by itself access URL vars - they must be passed in. [Here's a PHP example](http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.setparameter.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
substring-after($pPath, '=')
```

where `$pPath` is a reference to the global external `xsl:param` that contains the value of the url-like) file path, passed from the invoker of the transformation.

**In case that `pPath` contains more than one query-string parameter and you want to access the value of first one, then use**:

```
substring-after(substring-before(substring-after($pPath, '?'), '&amp;'), '=')
```

**If you are using XSLT 2.0 (XPath 2.0), then you can access the value of the the query-string-parameter named `$pQName` using**:

```
 substring-after
   (tokenize(substring-after($pPath, '?'), '&amp;')
         [starts-with(., concat($pQName, '='))],
   '='
   )
```

**Here are complete code examples**:

1. **The simplest case**:

. . .

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="pPath" select=
     "'C:/Documents and Settings/Saxon/output1/index.html?value=65abc'"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:sequence select="substring-after($pPath, '=')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted result is produced**:

```
65abc
```

.2. **When this transformation is performed on any XML document (not used**):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="pPath" select=
     "'C:/Documents and Settings/Saxon/output1/index.html?value=65abc&amp;x=1&amp;y=2'"/>
  <xsl:param name="pQName" select="'x'"/>   

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:sequence select=
     "substring-after
       (tokenize(substring-after($pPath, '?'), '&amp;')
             [starts-with(., concat($pQName, '='))],
      '='
      )"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**the wanted string (the value for the query-string parameter named `x`) is produced**:

```
1
```

Comment: i am still unclear how to do in this case - C:/Documents and Settings/Saxon/output1/index.html?value=65abc. I just need this part '65abc' from the url path

Comment: @user1402867: Don't you know how to use `<xsl:value-of>`?

Comment: i know how to use <xsl:value of>
I did something like this -
<xsl:variable name="pPath">output1/output3/index.html?value</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="temp" select="substring-after(substring-before(substring-after($pPath, '?'), '&amp;'), '=')" />

When I use this and run it. I don't get any output.

Comment: @user1402867: I have updated this answer with complete code samples.

Comment: @user1402867: I have done a series of edits to make the code formatted and readable.

Comment: thanks a lot @Dimitre Novatchev
actually the issue is my url is dynamic the 'value' keeps on changing. I am passing id in the url from a previous page

Comment: @user1402867: Every XSLT processor has its own (vendor-defined) API of invoking a transformation from code and passing to the transformation external parameter(s). It usually is possible also to do this using a vendor-provided command-line execution utility. You need to read the Saxon documentation to find and use the relevant information.

Comment: actually what i am doing is I have a one html file generated using xslt and now in this html i have links to other html file in which I am sending values through the link, so this goes through url. When this comes in url then i need to fetch the value and use it in XSLT for displaying further results.

Comment: @user1402867: Your last comment is unclear. Whenever you have the URL/filepath ready, then you can use the code in this answer. This is a complete and correct answer to your original question. If you have a new question (how to define and use variables in XSLT), please ask a new question. This question is fully answered.